# How import a lot of data from XML into an android app?

Tags: java, android, xml

How would you guys approach this? I am fairly new to android development.

To simplify, I have a trivia app I am working on, and I have to keep track of over 100 questions. Currently, I have a really long class file called`FactGenerator` with a bunch of code that looks like this

```
    //new question
    answerList.clear();
    question = "Example Question";

    answerList.add("Answer 1");
    answerList.add("Answer 2");
    answerList.add("Answer 3");
    answerList.add("Answer 4");

    explanation = "Reason why it is the answer";
    source = "Link to source";

    facts.addFact(new Fact(question,answerList,explanation,source));
```

I would use a csv, but wouldn't that cause issues if there were commas in the question? It seems like something XML would do, but I have no idea how create the facts other than this way. Any help or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Properly formatted and parsed CSV can handle commas in the data

Comment: Can u be a little clear?

Comment: @JavaDevil How would you be able to parse that in Java? Wouldn't it break .split()?

Comment: Using a proper CSV parser would handle this - It is valid to have comma's in the data for csv. Yes `spilt()` would break - but split is not the right way to parse it. If the data contains a comma then the data would be quoted in some way, normally with a `"`

Comment: Also using an database for this would probably be more efficient.

Comment: Do you have a library you recomend? @JavaDevil

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)